# After upgrading to 13.10 kernel panic - not syncing

Tags: kernel, 13.10, init

Until today I used 12.04. This afternoon I ugraded to 12.10 then 13.04 and finally to 13.10 .
Everything seemed normal during the updates. Afterwards on 13.10 I kept getting an error message related to oracle virtualbox. Since I don't use it anymore, I removed the package with synaptic. Following the next restart, I was greeted with a kernel panic screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLAaj.jpg).
I've tried to boot older kernels without success (3.8.0-33-generic, 3.5.0-43-generic, 3.2.0-56-generic) and the recovery mode didn't work either. (on the puprle background screen I can choose any options only to end up with the same result: a flash of the lines, all starting with error, then back to the recovery menu.)

How do I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in the error screen-shot leads to a issue with Astrill VPN. The rest just seams to be the kernel telling you that it has crashed. More info about the Astrill VPN issue can be found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139793

I would fix this by getting to the recovery root terminal and removing Astrill.

Start up the computer and press Shift just as Ubuntu starts (This can be tricky to time right). Select the root command prompt option when you get to the selection screen. Mount root as read and write with this command: `mount -o remount,rw /` . Then run `apt-get --purge astrill` . Then run `init 0` to restart the computer.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I cannot do anything in the recovery root terminal. If I choose root, a few lines will flash on a black background and I'm back to the recovery root terminal again. any other way I can remove Astrill?

Comment: You may be able to use a live DvD/USB to remove it, but I'm having a hard time finding any info on how to remove an application by using apt-get from a live session and changing your hard drive applications. You can certainly try deleting the offending file off your hard drive from a live session and see if it gets you anywhere though.